# How to use dig command of bulk/batch lookups to read hostnames from a text file?

Tags: shell, dig

I have a text file with 1.txt with  the following set of domains

```
adrive.com
amazon.com
amazon.ca
amazon.cn
amazon.co.jp
amazon.co.uk
amazon.com.au
amazon.com.br
amazon.com.mx
amazon.de
amazon.es
amazon.fr
amazon.in
amazon.it
console.aws.amazon.com
```

I did the following command to get the TXT record of a domain

```
dig TXT 1.txt
```

I am not sure,How to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to call `dig TXT` on each record of your file, you may want to use this command:

```
 cat 1.txt | xargs dig TXT
```

As stated in the `xargs` man:

xargs reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which can be protected with double or single quotes or a backslash) or newlines, and executes the command.

Edit: I just saw that dig does have a `-f` option, so you can also use:

```
dig TXT -f 1.txt
```

The output of the two commands are the same.